# Unwanted join condition using Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine

I am quite new to Doctrine2 and i am trying to learn it simply by using it.

I have two tables, group and user. Group can have a chairman, vice chairmen and members. My problem occurs when i try to get list of groups with user as chairman or vice chairman. This is my annotation of vicechairman in Group entity.

```
/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User") 
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="vicechairmen",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $vicechairmen;
```

Query builder

```
$qry = $this->entManager->getRepository("Entities\Local\Group")->createQueryBuilder("g");
$qry->leftJoin("g.vicechairmen", "gv", "WITH", "gv.id = g.id");
$qry->where($qry->expr()->eq('g.chairman', $id))->orWhere($qry->expr()->eq('gv.id', $id));
```

(kinda) Expected SQL query would be

```
SELECT g.id FROM `group` g
LEFT JOIN vicechairmen vg ON g.id = vg.group_id
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = vg.user_id
WHERE g.chairman_id = 4 OR u.id = 4
```

but i get (shortened select and renamed aliases)

```
SELECT g.id FROM `group` g
LEFT JOIN vicechairmen vg ON g.id = vg.group_id
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = vg.user_id AND u.id = g.id
WHERE g.chairman_id = 4 OR u.id = 4
```

the question is why is doctrine trying to connect user and group by their ids? And how to forbid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your annotation force it, in better word I should say you aggregate group table by user.  You should remove many to may join in your annotation to skip this. Doctrine will create many to many join when you have relation in your database fields.